# php convert txt as multi dimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

i have a file txt
and i need to convert it intto multi dimentionl array

```
/tost.txt 
------------------
where-when-who
cow-dog-cat
grape-aple-grape
------------------


<?php
$a = file("tost.php");
for($i = 0;$i<count($a);$i++)
{
$b = split("\-",$a[$i]);
}
?>
```

i try it but output :

```
 Array ( [0] => where [1] => when [2] => who )
 Array ( [0] => cow [1] => dog [2] => cat )
 Array ( [0] => maggo [1] => aple [2] => grape )
```

i had try to array_merge() , array_combine() , explode() , implode() ; no one s i need -->

i need output

```
 echo $b[0][0];   = "where" 
 echo $b[0][1];   = "when"
```

thank for help-

Comment: Create resulting array and put `$b` in it. Like this: `$result[] = $b`. So you'll get: `$b = split("\-",$a[$i]); $result[] = $b`. And put initialization line before `for` loop: `$result = array();`. After loop you'll get what you want in `$result`.

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
$result = Array();
$a = file("tost.php");
for($i = 0;$i<count($a);$i++) {
    $b = split("-",$a[$i]);
    $result[$i] = $b;
}
?>
```

Comment: Really - no comment, no explanation ..?